# MKAnnotationView: have texts below the annotationView and render the View

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

When I subclass `MKMarkerAnnotationView`, I get those nice text below the MarkerView for free, displaying title and subtitle.

When I subclass `MKAnnotationView`, I am completely free how I render the annotationView:

```
internal final class POIClusterView: MKAnnotationView {

override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        // render
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 40, height: 40))
        self.image = renderer.image { _ in

        ...
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine. But it doesn't display title and subtitle below like `MKMarkerAnnotationView`.

If I subclass `MKMarkerAnnotationView` and render my own image, I get those texts below, but the `MKMarkerAnnotationView` bubble is displayed on top of my own image.

How can I have both: render my own image and get the texts below for free?

The most straight forward idea might be to somehow turn off the rendering of the bubble of `MKMarkerAnnotationView`, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

After some experimenting I found a simple solution

```
// Inherit from MKMarkerAnnotationView to get the texts below the annotation for free
class POIMarkerClusterView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
    override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
        willSet {
            if let cluster = newValue as? MKClusterAnnotation {
                // set properties as usual
                // MKMarkerAnnotationView renders title and subtitle in the callout view 
                // and below the image if and where there is space:
                cluster.title = firstPoi.title
                if sortedPOIs.count == 2 {
                    cluster.subtitle = sortedPOIs.last?.title
                } else {
                    // default: MapKit shows something like "+2 more" and localizes it for us
                }

                // calculate statistics to render

                // render own image
                self.image = POIClusterImage(cityModel: cityModel, poiStatistics: poiStatistics, count: count)

                // MKMarkerAnnotationView's default rendering usually hides our own image.
                // so we make it invisible:
                self.glyphText = ""
                self.glyphTintColor = UIColor.clear
                self.markerTintColor = UIColor.clear

            }
        }
    }
}
```