# How to add title under annotation?

Tags: swift, mapkit, mkpointannotation

I managed to make my annotations with a personalized image by annotation and the title in the popup.
My question: Is it possible to also add the title below the annotation?
Thank you in advance for your feedback.

The view controller

```swift
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        let pageDecouverte = listeDesPoints[view.tag]
        selectedLieuDecouverte = pageDecouverte
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showPageDecouverte", sender: nil)
    }
    
    
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?
    {
        if !(annotation is MKPointAnnotation) {
            return nil
        }
        
        let annotationIdentifier = "location"
        var annotationView = carteRegion.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: (annotationIdentifier))
        
        
        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationIdentifier)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        }
        else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }
        
        if annotation is MyAnnotation {
            let imageName = (annotation as! MyAnnotation).imageName
            annotationView?.tag = (annotation as! MyAnnotation).tag
            if imageName != nil{
                let interetImage = UIImage(named: imageName!)
                annotationView!.image = interetImage
                
            }
            
        }
        annotationView?.clusteringIdentifier = annotationIdentifier
        annotationView?.canShowCallout = true
        annotationView?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type:.detailDisclosure)
        return annotationView
        
        
    }
}
```

For my `MyAnnotation`

```swift
import UIKit
import MapKit
import Parse


class MyAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    
    
    var imageName: String?
    var annotationTitle: String?
    var tag : Int = 0
    var pageDecouverte:PFPageDecouverte?
}
```

[image]

Comment: have you tried the special symbol  of new line "\n" and append the string on the annotation title string .

Comment: I don't see the connection with adding the title below the annotation. I would like to see the title under the annotation on the map display and keep the calloutAccessory to access my landing page

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `MKAnnotationView` use the subclass `MKMarkerAnnotationView` to render the title below the marker.

Also in `MyAnnotation` rename `annotationTitle` to `title`, then `MKMarkerAnnotationView` automatically knows what to render.

See the definition of protocol `MKAnnotation` to see why.

Comment: Important addition: set `glyphText = ""` and `markerTintColor = .clear` on the `MKMarkerAnnotationView` to prevent it showing a pin/cluster glyph over your own `image` 

(Spotted in https://stackoverflow.com/a/51389008)